# Weird Error In My system.log file Over and Over and Over

Tags: magento

In Magento Enterprise 1.8 I am getting a particular error over and over again and I was wondering if someone else has had this problem and what they did to solve it.

The error is:

> Invalid block type: Mage_CatalogInventory_Block_Qtyincrements

I am also seeing a lot of there:

> Invalid block type: Mage_Navadmin_Block_Navadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attempt to instantiate a block object, if Magento can't find the class  it will log the error, not render the block, and move along.

This happens in a few places throughout the code base, but the most likely place is in

```
File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
protected function _getBlockInstance($block, array $attributes=array())
{
    if (is_string($block)) {
        if (strpos($block, '/')!==false) {
            if (!$block = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($block)) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
            }
        }
        if (class_exists($block, false) || mageFindClassFile($block)) {
            $block = new $block($attributes);
        }
    }
    if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
    }
    return $block;
}
//...
public function getBlockSingleton($type)
{
    if (!isset($this->_helpers[$type])) {
        $className = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($type);
        if (!$className) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $type));
        }

        $helper = new $className();
        if ($helper) {
            if ($helper instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
                $helper->setLayout($this);
            }
            $this->_helpers[$type] = $helper;
        }
    }
    return $this->_helpers[$type];
}
```

So, your two specific errors.  Magento can't instantiate a

```
Mage_CatalogInventory_Block_Qtyincrements
```

That's probably because in the layout that ships with 1.8 the core code tried to use a block that would instantiate a

```
<block type="cataloginventory/qtyincrements" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" template="cataloginventory/qtyincrements.phtml"/>
```

This is a 1.8 bug.  I'd contact Magento Enterprise support for a patch.  As mentioned by @clockworkgeek it looks like [the community edition](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/195761/P0/) suffered a similar problem.  The patch in that thread is worth looking at for a fix, but I'd be wary of applying a patch meant for Enterprise Edition to Community Edition.

In your second error, Magento can't instantiate a

```
Mage_Navadmin_Block_Navadmin
```

There is no Navadmin module that ships with Enterprise 1.8.  Based on the block name, that means there's probably some block XML somewhere that looks something like

```
<block type="navadmin/navadmin"
```

My best guess if someone, at some point, installed [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/OlivertAr/extension/657/navigation-bar-administrator) on your site.  It's supposed to install files to (among other places)

```
app/code/community/Mage/Navadmin
```

Templates or XML layout files that reference the block are likely left on your system, but the actual class file that defines the block in

```
app/code/community/Mage/Navadmin/Block/Navadmin.php
```

is missing.

Comment: Magento gave us a patch for this issue and you were right about the other extension.

Answer (score 2):

There are some patch files on this page which fix the Qtyincrements message:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/195761/P0/

Comment: +1 for the thread, but I wouldn't blindly add those patches to the 1.8 Enterprise edition.  That thread is dealing with a 1.4.1 CE release, and the two products are separate branches.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. With Magento Enterprise and Community being so different I am very hesitant to push a Community file into Enterprise. I may have to give that support a try on this one. I'll post any findings that I get in case someone else has this issue.

Comment: They might have already fixed it in 1.9, especially since the patch came from their own staff.

Comment: @clcokworkgeek The missing class is there in 1.9, so the Mage_CatalogInventory_Block_Qtyincrements problem should be fixed. Navadmin's a custom module though, so an upgrade (or the patch) won't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I only find references to 'Invalid block type' in `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::_getBlockInstance()`.

The error seems to be caused either when a block does not inherit from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` or the block cannot be loaded by it's short format due to a lacking in the appropriate `config.xml` file somewhere.

- Do the classes actually exist on your system?
- What elements are using them in the `layout/*.xml` files?
- Is there something up, like a syntax error, with the `config.xml` in `Mage/{Navadmin,CatalogInventory}/etc/config.xml`? (configuration file locations are an educated guess)